# Registry Pattern location of variable declared

Tags: magento

As Magento uses

Mage::register('somevar',$object);

Then use

Mage::registery('somevar') to get the data anywhere in the system.

Now, 
Is there any quick way to find out the location of the declaration of the 'somevar'?
Can we locate that file and line quickly?

Or we have to go through all the class and find it all manually.

Comment: hu ? I don't understand the question... are you asking for the shortcut for searching a string in your IDE ? : Ctrl + F

Comment: For example in core class Magneto uses Mage::registry('product') at several places now how can I find the Mage::register at first place? It could be anywhere in any class

Comment: @Bixi OP question on my answer provides insight into his/her thinking, FWIW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep`,`awk`, or your IDE should suffice for finding strings. `grep` example:

```
grep -srn0 "Mage::register('current" ./
```

Output:

```
./app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product.php:324:            Mage::register('current_category', $category);
./app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product.php:328:        Mage::register('current_product', $product);
./app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Convert/Parser/Product.php:384:            Mage::register('current_imported_inventory', $inventoryFields);
./app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Category.php:94:        Mage::register('current_category_filter', $this->getCategory(), true);
./app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php:57:        Mage::register('current_category', $category);
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, in your output first line and the last line is the same('current_category') but different classes. Isn't the global register variable names supposed to be unique through out the system? otherwise how would be come to know which one we are after?

Comment: Registry entries are subject to being created in the first place, and therefore subject to application execution path. For example, if request routing goes through the `CategoryController` and the product helper is invoked, then the attempt to register `current_category` could happen twice. There is a calltime flag for whether subsequent attempts to set the same value will throw an exception or not; see [`Mage::register()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/Mage.php#L216)